# Implementing ng2-completer with custom search

Tags: angular

I am currently using *ng2-completer* for *angular 2*, it works well with search with keywords.

I have 2 tables :

- Artists
- Shows

One artist can have multiple shows, it's a one-to-many relationship.

I need to search using the artist's name, when I search using artist name it has to show all "shows" of particular "artist".

This is my code :

```
this.dataService = completerService.local(this.searchData, 'artisName', 'artisName');
```

Comment: Did you find any answer? The provided answer is not my solution. What I want is that when I search with a space then the search must be performed like before space characters on one field and after space characters for other field.

Answer (score 0):

The best option to do that would be to create a `Subject` that will emit the modified shows list to a `dataSource` whenever a new artist is selected.

```js
public artistsDataService: CompleterData;
public showsDataService: CompleterData;

private showsSubject = new Subject();

constructor(completerService: CompleterService) {
    this.artistsDataService = completerService.local(this.artists, 'artisName', 'artisName');
    this.showsDataService = completerService.local(this.showsSubject, 'showName', 'showName');
}

public onArtistsSelected(selectedItem: CompleterItem) {
    if (selectedItem) {
        const artistShows = this.showsDataService.filter(...);
        this.showsDataService.next(artistShows);
    } else {
        this.showsDataService.next([]);
    }
}
```